# Initialize UIView with CGRectMake not changes origin point [Objective-C]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing objective-C app and I want create a UIView with my custom values and there is a problem that i can not fix.

This code works fine:

```
CGRect rect;
rect.origin.x = 10; rect.origin.y = 20;
rect.size.width = 30; rect.size.height = 40;
NSLog(@" %@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
```

But this one in NSLOG returns origin point to (0,0) and width and height fine:

```
UIView* aux = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,30,40)];
NSLog(@" %@",NSStringFromCGRect(aux.bounds));
```

Is there any problem in initialization of `UIView` with `CGRectMake`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are printing view.bounds, but not view.frame.
Just change it to:

```
NSLog(@" %@",NSStringFromCGRect(aux.frame));
```

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the *bounds* of a view are always (0, 0). You have to change your code to

```
NSLog(@" %@",NSStringFromCGRect(aux.frame));
```

See Apple's documentation for an explanation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW6)

Answer (score 0):

First a recap on the question: frame, bounds and center and theirs relationships.

**Frame** A view's frame (CGRect) is the position of its rectangle in the superview's coordinate system. By default it starts at the top left.

**Bounds** A view's bounds (CGRect) expresses a view rectangle in its own coordinate system.

**Center** A center is a CGPoint expressed in terms of the superview's coordinate system and it determines the position of the exact center point of the view.

You need to use:

```
NSLog(@" %@",NSStringFromCGRect(aux.frame));
```

Answer (score 0):

The **bounds** of an `UIView` is the rectangle, expressed as a `location (x,y)` and `size (width,height)` relative to its own coordinate system (0,0).

The **frame** of an `UIView` is the rectangle, expressed as a `location (x,y)` and `size (width,height)` relative to the superview it is contained within.

So you need to use view.frame in your log method as-

```
NSLog(@" %@",NSStringFromCGRect(aux.frame));
```